# Turn an array of values into an array of variables

Tags: php, arrays

**Update**

After the initial feedback I got that my question is unclear, I decided to start over and ask it with more context, and clearer details. See [Many php mysqli queries from one prepared statement without knowing how many parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277450/many-php-mysqli-queries-from-one-prepared-statement-without-knowing-how-many-par)

Sorry about the confusion.

**Original Question**

I'd like to dynamically turn an associative array:

```
$array =
[
    'key' => 'AX-2NV',
    'id' => 2
]
```

into an array of variables:

```
[$key,$id] // where $key='AX-2NV' and $id=2
```

When I have no control over the input array.  The variable creation is simple enough with the `extract` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
extract($array); // will create the variables $key and $id
```

The challenge is how do I get the resulting variables in an array when I don't know ahead of time what the variable names or the input array size will be?

This may be irrelevant but the objective is to make a call to the function `call_user_func_array` and pass it the array `[$key,$id]` as the parameters of the function I'm calling. I've considered doing simply

```
call_user_func_array($function,array_values($array));
```

But I still need a handle to these variables for further processing, so just using the values and moving on is not an option.

Comment: Why can't you just use the `$array` that you created in the first place? I don't see any point to extracting it.

Comment: What do you mean by *further processing* you can easily loop through your array and do whatever you want. The problem is not clear!!!

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me rewrite the question to make the problem more clear. I'll be back.

Comment: I asked the same question more clearly I hope at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277450/many-php-mysqli-queries-from-one-prepared-statement-without-knowing-how-many-par

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array containing a list of all the keys from another array with `array_keys()`.

`extract()` may have security implications, I hope this is some sort of hypothetical problem because otherwise you should be fetching the data you need from the array itself, and not converting its items into global variables.

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me rewrite the question to make the problem more clear. I'll be back.

Comment: I asked the same question more clearly (I hope) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277450/many-php-mysqli-queries-from-one-prepared-statement-without-knowing-how-many-par

Answer (score 1):

Very strange idea, but...

```
foreach ($array as $_k => $_v) {
    $$_k = $_v;
}
```

So... your

```
$array =
[
    'key' => 'AX-2NV',
    'id' => 2
]
```

Will be

```
$key = 'AX-2NV';
$id = 2;
```

**EDIT**

I understood... ))

```
$newArray = array_values($array)
```

That is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't solve my problem but upvote because it inspired me to a solution.  Getting variables out of the array was not the tricky part for me. `extract($array)` would also create `$key` and `$id` vars as I stated in the OP.  What you helped me realize though is a way to get a handle on those vars even though I don't know their names.  Within the loop you created I can store a reference to `$$_k` in an array, and access it later using the array index.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad that could help you ) [PHP: Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Your edit isn't it. I had already considered `array_values` before posting (see the last line of code in my original Q).  It's my fault b/c I did a poor job of explaining what I was trying to do. I posted a better explanation of my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277450/many-php-mysqli-queries-from-one-prepared-statement-without-knowing-how-many-par), but your answer here put my mind in the right direction.

Comment: I answered [to your new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277450/many-php-mysqli-queries-from-one-prepared-statement-without-knowing-how-many-par)