# Many php mysqli queries from one prepared statement without knowing how many parameters

Tags: php, mysql

This is a better explanation of the problem I woefully tried to explain [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277102/turn-an-array-of-values-into-an-array-of-variables?noredirect=1#comment63973585_38277102) .

I wish to execute multiple queries that all use the same prepared statement, like so (working code):

```
$params = [
    ['age'=>10,'id'=>1], ['age'=>12,'id'=>2],
];
$param_types = 'ii';
$sql_template = "UPDATE mytable SET age = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_template);
$stmt->bind_param($param_types, $age, $id);

foreach($params as $param):
    $age = $param['age'];
    $id = $param['id'];
    $stmt->execute();
endforeach;
```

I'd like to put this logic in a function, and use it like so:

```
queries_from_template($sql_template, $params, $param_types);
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to write the function given that I don't know what `$params` will look like. Here is what I have so far:

```
function queries_from_template($sql_template,$params,$param_types){

    //$mysqli is a handle to a live mysqli DB connection
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_template);

    //build the array that holds the arguments of $stmt->bind_param
    //result will be eg: ['ii', 10, 1]
    $bind_param_args = array_merge([$param_types],array_values($params[0]));

    //call bind_param with a dynamic number of arguments
    call_user_func_array([$stmt,"bind_param"],$bind_param_args);

    foreach($params as $param):
        /* THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK*/
        // I need a handle to each of the parameters that were bound with
        // bind_param so that I can set them to the correct value
        // on each loop before I execute.
        // Remember I don't know how many parameters there are

        //run query with current value of parameters
        $stmt->execute();
    endforeach;

    //todo: free results, close connection, disconnect
}
```

Comment: This piece of code may be useful to you: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8906fc8bcb87c365de3874003723309e you basically use `Database::Query('UPDATE mytable SET age = ? WHERE id = ?', 'ii', 10, 1)` and then `Database::Query('UPDATE mytable SET age = ? WHERE id = ?', 'ii', 12, 2)`. Even though the query is repeated, the class will recognize they are the same and will reused the cached prepared statement that was instanced on the first query. This may not be what you are looking for but I'm sure this code will help you with whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Re-using the cached prepared statement helps. However the many function calls are still costly:  if I have 1M queries, it will execute 1M calls to `Query()`, to `$stmt->bind_param`, to `$stmt->execute`, to `$stmt->get_result`.  In the stated problem, the only function called 1M times is the `$stmt->execute()` itself.

Comment: I'm sure you can find a way to adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement :-)

Comment: If you are truly calling it 1M times (or even 10K times), then a bulk update is the way to go. It will be at least 50 times faster

Comment: If by bulk update you mean `multi_query` instead of looping through `execute` calls, it's about 78x faster than my solution, and about 185x faster than Leonid's solution according to my tests.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the specific var names used to refer to parameters in `$stmt->bind_param(...)` don't matter, I changed the input from an associative array to an indexed array

Before:

```
$params = [
    ['age'=>10,'id'=>1], ['age'=>12,'id'=>2],
];
```

Now:

```
$params = [
    [10,1], [12,2],
];
```

This makes it easier to loop through parameters on each query.  Below is my solution:

```
/*
 * Executes multiple queries from the same prepared statement
 */
function queries_from_template($sql_template, $params, $param_types){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_template);

    $handles = [];//holds references to parameters
    for($i=0; $i<count($params[0]);$i++):
        $varname = "param_$i";
        $$varname = null; //define variables $param_0, $param_1...
        $handles[] = &$$varname; //store references to the new variables
    endfor;

    //call $stmt->bind_param: bind to the new variables
    $bind_param_args = array_merge([$param_types],$handles);
    call_user_func_array([$stmt,'bind_param'],$bind_param_args);

    foreach($params as $param):
        foreach($handles as $index => &$handle):
            // assign the values for the current execute loop
            // to the created vars ($param_0, $param_1...)
            $handle = $param[$index];
        endforeach;

        $stmt->execute(); //execute, todo: error handling          
    endforeach;

    $stmt->close(); $mysqli->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Associated sets
$params_sets = [
    ['age'=>10,'id'=>1], 
    ['age'=>12,'id'=>2],
];

// Param names in right order
$param_names = ['age', 'id'];

// Param types in right order
$param_types = 'ii';

// SQL template
$sql_template = "UPDATE mytable SET age = ? WHERE id = ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql_template);

// Ok, let's do it!
foreach ($params_sets as $params) {
    // Collecting parameters for bind_param function 
    // You need to do it every iteration!
    // First parameter is $param_types
    $bind_params = [$param_types];
    // Now let's add every parameter in right order using $param_names
    foreach ($param_names as $param_name) {
        $bind_params[] = $params[$param_name];
    }
    // Ok! Call bind_param method from $stmt object with $bind_params as parameters
    call_user_func_array([$stmt, 'bind_param'], $bind_params);
    // And execute query
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Leonid. I have a solution (posted it here too) that calls `bind_param` only one time as per my original question. I used your variable variables suggestion from the other board :-)